# RewriteRule / RewriteCond help when two "keywords" show in the one query string

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting

Currently I have this in my `.htaccess` file:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
Options -MultiViews
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /forum/
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule \.(jpeg|jpg|gif|png)$ /forum/public/404.php [NC,L]

RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} (?:^|&)app=core(?:&|$) [NC]
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} (?:^|&)section=register(?:&|$) [NC]
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ http://www.mysite.com/register.php? [NC,L,R=302]

RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} (?:^|&)app=core(?:&|$) [NC]
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} (?:^|&)section=login(?:&|$) [NC]
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ http://www.mysite.com/login.php? [NC,L,R=302]

RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} (?:^|&)app=core(?:&|$) [NC]
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} (?:^|&)section=lostpass(?:&|$) [NC]
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ http://www.mysite.com/retrieve_password.php? [NC,L,R=302]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /forum/index.php [L]
</IfModule>
```

The one I need help with is this one:

```
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} (?:^|&)app=core(?:&|$) [NC]
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} (?:^|&)section=login(?:&|$) [NC]
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ http://www.mysite.com/login.php? [NC,L,R=302]
```

Currently this will redirect something like:

```
http://www.mysite.com/forum/index.php?app=core&module=global&section=login
```

The `&module=global` isn't required so as I'm sure you can tell it only looks for the `app` & `section` parameters.

However the problem is, it also redirects the logout link I want to redirect somewhere else as it also contains `app=core` & `&section=login`.

Here is an example:

```
http://www.mysite.com/forum/index.php?app=coree&module=global&section=login&do=logout&k=xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx
```

So basically the login should still redirect as above *unless* it has `&do=logout` in the query string; in that case I want to redirect it somewhere else.

How can I go about doing this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change your rule to:

```
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} (?:^|&)app=core(?:&|$) [NC]
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} (?:^|&)section=login(?:&|$) [NC]
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} !(?:^|&)do=logout(?:&|$) [NC]
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ http://www.mysite.com/login.php? [NC,L,R=302]
```

Here `RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} !(?:^|&)do=logout(?:&|$) [NC]` will skip redirect if `&do=logout` is present in the query string.

**EDIT:** As per comments:

```
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} (?:^|&)app=core(?:&|$) [NC]
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} (?:^|&)section=login(?:&|$) [NC]
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} (?:^|&)do=logout(?:&|$) [NC]
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ http://www.mysite.com/logout.php? [NC,L,R=302]
```

Comment: Thanks! ...and how would I do one for the logout without affecting the login? Guess I just need to look for `app=core` & `do=logout` ?